# Not able to run a simple beam pipeline

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-execution-plan

I have a simple sql query with some aggregations, there is no problem with the query itself, I am looking into its execution plan and don't know where are those aggregations in the plan come from the query itself:

Table:
[image]

Query (this query contains string operation, group by, order by and join, purpose: to get the reporting period that total amount increased certain target over the years):

```
 WITH cte
     AS (SELECT Year(orderdate)                       AS yr,
                Month(orderdate)                      AS mon,
                Ltrim(Rtrim(Str(Year(orderdate)))) + '-'
                + Ltrim(Rtrim(Str(Month(orderdate)))) AS theMonth,
                Sum(totalamount)                      AS theAmount
         FROM   [order]
         GROUP  BY Year(orderdate),
                   Month(orderdate),
                   Ltrim(Rtrim(Str(Year(orderdate)))) + '-'
                   + Ltrim(Rtrim(Str(Month(orderdate)))))
SELECT TOP 3 cte.themonth,
             cte_prev.themonth                      AS thePrevMonth,
             cte.theamount,
             cte_prev.theamount                     AS thePrevAmount,
             ( cte.theamount - cte_prev.theamount ) AS diff
FROM   cte
       JOIN cte cte_prev
         ON cte.yr = cte_prev.yr + 1
            AND cte.mon = cte_prev.mon
WHERE  ( cte.theamount - cte_prev.theamount ) / cte_prev.theamount > 0.8
ORDER  BY ( cte.theamount - cte_prev.theamount ) / cte_prev.theamount DESC
```

Execution plan:

[image]

I wonder how can I create a better/simpler query to calculate the difference between two reporting period? and the string trimming is really annoying here: why there is no simple and single trim but have to ltrim and rtrim?

Comment: The `stream aggregate` looks like it is doing aggregations.  This is obviously SQL Server, so I added that tag.

Comment: Regarding your last question about `TRIM`, the T-SQL `TRIM` function was introduced with SQL Server 2017 so that can simplify the code although I wouldn't expect a significant performance difference.

Comment: Aggregating without the extra string conversion might help. It is far better to let the consumer of the resultset format year and month however it sees fit.